# open ai api response having extra string at the first line

Tags: javascript, openai-api

I am using open ai api in node js to generate code.

```html
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

async function name() {
    prompt = `create a router config.js file with name as routerConfig for files page1.js only using BrowserRouter,Route and Routes tag from react-router-dom.Import BrowserRouter,Route and Routes tag from react-router-dom.Enclose all Route tag with Routes tag.Don't use Switch.Import files from ./filename in lowercase.In Route tag,for path give /filename itself as path value`;
        console.log("prompt",prompt);
        const configuration = new Configuration({
          apiKey: "API-KEY",
        });
        const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
        console.log("prompt coming", prompt);
        const codeResponse = await openai
          .createCompletion({
            model: "text-davinci-003",
            prompt: prompt,
            temperature: 0.7,
            max_tokens: 400,
            top_p: 1,
            frequency_penalty: 0,
            presence_penalty: 0,
          })
          .then(async (codeResponse) => {
            console.log(codeResponse.data.choices);
            var code = codeResponse.data.choices[0].text;
            console.log(code);
          });
}

name();
```

The response is coming but on top of the code some additional lines are coming. I will add one logs for better understanding.I have attached the response below. As you can see in the first line it has some string.

```html
 and for component give UpperCaseFileName as component value

import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'

import Page1 from './page1';

const RouterConfig = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/page1" component={Page1} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default RouterConfig;
```

I dont know where this line is getting appended from. It is causing errors while running the code

Answer (score 1):

The main reason you are getting the extra text at the top of your response is because of your prompt.

`create a router config.js file with name as routerConfig for files page1.js only using BrowserRouter,Route and Routes tag from react-router-dom.Import BrowserRouter,Route and Routes tag from react-router-dom.Enclose all Route tag with Routes tag.Don't use Switch.Import files from ./filename in lowercase.In Route tag,for path give /filename itself as path value`

If you notice in the prompt it does not terminate with a full stop (period). Therefore, GPT-3 completion endpoint will attempt to 'complete' your prompt. Hence it is adding the additional text.

As GPT-3 is a Natural Language Processing platform grammar is ver important. You should fix up your prompt to place spaces between the sentences.

`react-router-dom.Import` could be read by GPT-3 as a file name.

Make sure you always have punctuation at the end of your prompt (.?!) otherwise GPT-3 may attempt to complete your sentence. Here is your corrected prompt. When I used this I got the response correctly.

`Create a router config.js file with the name routerConfig for files page1.js, only using BrowserRouter, Route and Routes tag from react-router-dom. Import BrowserRouter, Route and Routes tag from react-router-dom. Enclose all Route tag with Routes tag. Don't use Switch. Import files from ./filename in lowercase. In Route tag, for path give /filename itself as path value.`